# Was asbestos ever available in in a wool form for spacing pipes from studs??

Tags: plumbing, asbestos

House pipes have a woolly fluff around them, at the holders. What's the chance that this is asbestos?

House is 1960s

[image: pipe insulation]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only way to know is to get the material tested.

Comment: Asbestos has a bad rap for being deadly, which it is for the workers using it everyday for years.  If you are concern, a pair of gloves, a mask and a plastic bag and you can remove it and replace with something else or leave it alone.

Comment: Are you sure that was placed there by humans as a "spacer", and not by various and sundry critters who have visited the house over the last 60 years? That very much looks like it could be mouse or bird nesting material. Testing is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: The portion shown is fluffy.  We have some material wrapped around hot water pipes.  They call it lagging and is more of a jute-like material mixed with wool.  Are there any more samples of the material that you can post

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say as asbestos cannot be identified by visual inspection.

Have a sample tested and then you will know for sure.

See:

[Asbestos](https://www.asbestos.com/exposure/home/)

To quote:

> It’s extremely difficult to identify asbestos just by looking at it,
> so you need to send samples to a lab for testing.
>
> Homeowners can collect samples and have them tested, but it’s much
> safer for you and your family to hire a trained asbestos professional
> for the job.
>
> Search for “asbestos inspection” online to find a licensed expert in
> your area. The U.S. Department of Commerce offers a list of accredited
> asbestos laboratories online.

Comment: If you hire someone to come collect the sample, they'll probably come in their scary isolation suits _because they do this all day every day_. If the homeowner collects a _single sample_ to be tested, _most likely_ nothing more than a well-fitted fine dust mask and a gentle touch disturbing the mass as little as possible will do just fine.